# Program Fails for Spark_Home at foreachPartition with change in location of database load utility from one module to another

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I am working on a python spark project, where initially i had written a script to load dataframe to postgres for a particular client which include a utility function which loads data to postgres.

```
df.rdd.repartition(self.__max_conn).foreachPartition(
        lambda iterator: load_utils.load_tab_postgres(conn_prop=conn_prop,
                                           tab_name=<tablename>,
                                           iterator=iterator))
```

Initially the entire code was in single module including the above code snippet and load_utils(), which was working perfectly fine.

Later i had to extract common code including load_utils into a base module that could be used in different client modules. This is when the same code failed with below error:

> File
>   "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.13.1-1.cdh5.13.1.p0.2/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 764, in foreachPartition   File
>   "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.13.1-1.cdh5.13.1.p0.2/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1004, in count   File
>   "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.13.1-1.cdh5.13.1.p0.2/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 995, in sum   File
>   "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.13.1-1.cdh5.13.1.p0.2/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 869, in fold   File
>   "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.13.1-1.cdh5.13.1.p0.2/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 771, in collect   File
>   "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.13.1-1.cdh5.13.1.p0.2/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in **call**   File
>   "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.13.1-1.cdh5.13.1.p0.2/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py",
>   line 45, in deco   File
>   "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.13.1-1.cdh5.13.1.p0.2/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
>   line 308, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
>   occurred while calling
>   z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 18 in stage 126.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   18.3 in stage 126.0 (TID 24028, tbsatad6r15g24.company.co.us, executor 242): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File
>   "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.13.1-1.cdh5.13.1.p0.2/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 98, in main
>       command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.13.1-1.cdh5.13.1.p0.2/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
>   line 164, in _read_with_length
>       return self.loads(obj)   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.13.1-1.cdh5.13.1.p0.2/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
>   line 422, in loads
>       return pickle.loads(obj)   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/basemodule/**init**.py", line 12, in
>   
>       import basemodule.entitymodule.base   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/basemodule/entitymodule/base.py", line
>   12, in    File
>   "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/basemodule/contexts.py", line 17, in
>      File
>   "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.13.1-1.cdh5.13.1.p0.2/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/conf.py",
>   line 104, in **init**
>       SparkContext._ensure_initialized()   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.13.1-1.cdh5.13.1.p0.2/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 245, in _ensure_initialized
>       SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway()   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.13.1-1.cdh5.13.1.p0.2/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 48, in launch_gateway
>       SPARK_HOME = os.environ["SPARK_HOME"]   File "/dhcommon/dhpython/python/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in
>   **getitem**
>       raise KeyError(key) KeyError: 'SPARK_HOME'

Below is the spark_submit command to run the code:

> spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-class-path
>   postgresql-42.2.4.jre6.jar --jars
>   spark-csv_2.10-1.4.0.jar,commons-csv-1.4.jar,postgresql-42.2.4.jre6.jar
>   --py-files project.egg driver_file.py

In both above scenarios the load_utils file containing "load_tab_postgres" method will be bundled in project.egg.